# Flexget Cron job failing

Tags: python, cron

I've had FlexGet running on an automated cron job for over a year with no problems, however for the past week or so it's failed to run.

I found the following error log in my /var/mail file but I'm not sure what to do about it.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ERROR LOG:

```
From [snipped]  Wed Jul  2 10:30:04 2014
Return-Path: [snipped]
X-Original-To: [snipped]
Delivered-To: [snipped]
Received: by [snipped] (Postfix, from userid 1000)
        id AB9BD420D10; Wed,  2 Jul 2014 10:30:04 -0700 (PDT)
From: root@[snipped] (Cron Daemon)
To: [snipped]
Subject: Cron [snipped] /usr/local/bin/flexget --cron
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/[snipped]>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=[snipped]>
Message-Id: <20140702173004.AB9BD420D10@[snipped]>
Date: Wed,  2 Jul 2014 10:30:04 -0700 (PDT)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flexget", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('FlexGet==1.1', 'console_scripts', 'flexget')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flexget/__init__.py", line 28, in main
    manager = Manager(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flexget/manager.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.db_cleanup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flexget/manager.py", line 666, in db_cleanup
    fire_event('manager.db_cleanup', session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flexget/event.py", line 97, in fire_event
    event(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flexget/event.py", line 21, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flexget/plugins/generic/db_vacuum.py", line 21, in on_cleanup
    session.execute('VACUUM')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 917, in execute
    clause, params or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1449, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1584, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1698, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1691, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 331, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) database disk image is malformed u'VACUUM' ()
```

Comment: Also worth noting: when I run flexget manually I get no errors.. But every time it runs via cron it fails with the errors quoted above.

Comment: is there any chance you have cron jobs overlapping (i.e. they have started taking longer recently, or some new ones have been added), as suggested in the following thread: https://github.com/wpoa/open-access-media-importer/issues/113

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mc110. I don't think that's happening. I've rebooted the system, so it's unlikely there's a hung process keeping the db open, and the cron job runs every half hour, but only takes about 40 seconds to complete when run manually. I've just grepped the process list for "flexget", no results.

Comment: Are you in a position to delete/flush the db file? Their data migrations have had the occasional hiccup.